# Owncloud connect ipad to my local owncloud

Tags: ipad, owncloud

ive just installed owncloud and made a "`local"` on my linux machine. i am trying to connect my ipad which is on the same network to it but i do not know what the server adress is?

i cannot seem to find alot of documentation on the subject so i was hoping someone here would be able to help me out?

The server is on my local machine as `localhost/owncloud`

Is that the adress i need to use?

because if so it says that it cannot find the server

Comment: This is not a programming question. Ask on [su]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To this kind of questions you should go to the ownCloud forums at:
http://forum.owncloud.org/

Anyway

Linux/Unix:
Type on your terminal "ifconfig" and search with interface are you using (eth0 for ethernet for example) and there is your ip

Windows:
Type on your terminal "ipconfig" and search with interface are you using. You also can go to the network options and check it.